# Hidden Password for C# Login Screen - Help & Ideas

Tags: c#, authentication

I want to hide a password in a text box. The password is hard coded, which I know is not great but is all that is required for the project.

At the moment I am using click event but then when tab is used does not implement the code.

How can this be done? This is my current code:

```
// Password Text Box Click Event

private void txtPassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

// When password text box clixked, the watermark will disappear

txtPassword.Text = "";

txtPassword.ForeColor = Color.Black;

txtPassword.PasswordChar = '●'; // Password masking for added security

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reason why that code is not executed when using tab key is because it is a Click event handler. Try using the Enter event instead so that your code gets executed when the textbox receives focus.

Edit:

```
private void txtPassword_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtPassword.Text = "";

        txtPassword.ForeColor = Color.Black;

        txtPassword.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
    }

    private void txtPassword_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtPassword.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            txtPassword.ForeColor = Color.Gray;

            txtPassword.Text = "Enter password";

            txtPassword.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;

            SelectNextControl(txtPassword, true, true, false, true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I tried the Enter event and have got it working.

Comment: Also, you can pair it with a Leave event and put back the watermark in case the user has left the textbox empty.

Comment: You should mark the answer that helped you best so others could see it is suitable for that kind of problem.

Comment: Why is the SelectNextControl needed in the txtPassword_Leave event?
I've tried without it and when I 'tab' to the next control, focus stays with the txtPassword box. I don't understand why this should be so.

Answer (score 5):

Just use the UseSystemPasswordChar property on the textbox.  Set it to true.  For more customization, Set the PasswordChar property so something like * or some other commonly accepted password character.

Comment: I have used the other answer and have now got it working so think I'll stick with that, but thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for the GotFocus method, try the following:

```
this.txtPassword.GotFocus += OnFocus;

private void OnFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   txtPassword.useSystemPasswordChar = true;
}
```